# Triage review asks me to upvote, but not giving such an option

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, triage

As you can see, there are no voting buttons in the Triage review on Stack Overflow:

> [image: Triage review]

Yet, sometimes when I click "looks OK" I get a message that I should upvote good questions.

Even if I open the question by clicking the link to it and upvote, then go back and click "looks OK" I still get the message.

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system), the voting arrows are removed on purpose, however I think the "you can upvote" message should not be displayed when reviewing, since we can't do that via the review itself.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system (voted for a wrong dupe by mistake, @rene can you please cast a vote?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do not see this as a duplicate, I have added some text to the question. I see this as a bug that SO keeps telling me to cast votes when I can't.

Comment: It's easy enough to middle click the question title and upvote there. It shouldn't be part of the review itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard and the point is that if it shouldn't be part of the review itself, then the review shouldn't ask/remind you to upvote. This question isn't asking why there is no option to vote (which is what the dupe does) - it is asking why the system encourages you to vote on review where you don't have the option to vote in the first place - something that may be unintended. The point now should be... can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Thank you! That is what I'm trying to say. It's not about the up/down vote. I do agree with the text in the link that downvoting in the review is not "ok", but upvoting should in my opinion be ok. I mean if you see a question that is perfectly described with code and comments, why not be able to upvote? But that is not the point I'm geting at in this thread. It's the annyoing reminder to upvote good questions.

Comment: And I am pretty sure that the reminder is caused by every review queue using the same "logic". So, the reminder that was crafted to encourage voting on first posts/late answers and such now is bugging off people on things like close/edit/reopen review where you don't have the ability to vote.

Answer (score 6):

This does appear to have been a bug - you shouldn't be asked to vote unless you *can* vote. Should appear like this:

[image]

I can't speculate on what might've been happening when you saw this, but [there was a bug here in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378164/in-triage-if-a-questions-consensus-is-looks-ok-the-gui-suggests-i-can-vote/383040#383040) and while I'm pretty sure that particular bug didn't exist when you posted this report... I wouldn't be surprised at all of something similar happened back in 2016.

Thanks for the report; please let me know if you encounter this again.

Comment: Shog, we recently [discussed in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48714236#48714236) one particular quirk that triaged questions with pending close votes/flags aren't pushed to close queue until triage is completed, do you by chance remember if this was intended? One specifically weird side effect of that seems to be that triaged questions get de-prioritised when they finally enter close queue because of age. (if you prefer this as separate meta question I can post it, just let me know)

Comment: It is intentional, @gnat (the idea being to let Triage pre-screen stuff going to Close). It *shouldn't* de-prioritize anything, since priority should be based on the age of the *task*, not the *question*. But I'm going from memory there - if it works otherwise then likely causing other problems too.

Comment: but the triage completion doesn't count as _task_ when question enters the close queue (neither do flags/votes cast from this review), do I understand that right? If yes then triage essentially de-prioritises it compared to more recent votes / flags / reviews on other questions outside of triage

Comment: Remember, @gnat: review is an abstraction layer over the rest of the system. A question may appear in multiple queues, but is a unique task in each queue; a task result - an action taken in review - may correspond to a flag or a vote, but every flag or vote is not a review result. As a result, a question entering the Close queue after being held up in Triage is as fresh to that queue as one entering immediately upon receiving a vote, or indeed one of advanced age whose previous votes have all long ago aged away... They sort the same; their priority starts and drifts per this session in queue.

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Whenever the reminder is shown, *that* is when you can vote, and only then. This functionality is unique to Triage; all other queues either allow no voting at all, or allow voting in the first page on all posts. (In fact, the Looks OK result page is also unique to Triage.)

The reasoning for this is the same as [some problems for FP/LA that have not yet been fixed](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/158761): reviewers of at-risk posts should be encouraged to vote on them, and having multiple reviewers is necessary for review reliability, but having multiple *voters* in review tends to create unhealthily focused vote streams. So, in Triage, only one reviewer can ever vote on any given review without going out of their way. (See also [Shog's more recent post about Triage voting](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280593).)

Fresh screenshot with demonstration upvote to show how this turns out:

[image: Upvoted question that was determined to Look OK]

So this is not a bug. Everything is working fine if you look in the right places.