# Why can I not upvote in triage review after system tells me ”The consensus is: this post Looks OK“?

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage

When I review the triage queue, I flag a question to `Looks OK`, and system tells me:

> Thanks! The consensus is: this post Looks OK.
>   Please remember to upvote clear, useful, well-researched questions to encourage their authors and help answerers identify them!`

So I want to upvote, but **upvote button no response**. I encountered this problem many times (almost 100% reproduced). I only have to open a new link and upvote.

[image]

I think maybe it is duplicate of *[In Triage, if a question's consensus is "Looks OK", the GUI suggests I can vote on it after the review, but I cannot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378164/in-triage-if-a-questions-consensus-is-looks-ok-the-gui-suggests-i-can-vote)*, but I haven't got a solution.

Is it bug? And it wasn't fixed yet?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323792/triage-review-asks-me-to-upvote-but-not-giving-such-an-option